# Filter using a many-to-many table MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, filter

I have the following tables (other tables ommitted for simplicity).  1 is for all of the people, 2 is for the sports that those people play.  I am using php to allow a user to see a list of people.  They can filter by a person's name, or by the sports they play.  So, I want the ability to see all people that play for example baseball and football.

```
create table people (
  id int,
  name varchar(50)
  );

create table people_to_sports (
  personID int,
  sportID int,
  primary key(personID,sportID)
  );
```

Basically my question is, how can I use people_to_sports to get a list of all people that play sport 1 and sport 2 for example?

I have a sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a149/10).

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT
  personID
FROM
  people_to_sports
WHERE
  sportID IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY
  personID
HAVING
  COUNT(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT personID, COUNT(personID) AS cnt
FROM people_to_sports
WHERE sportID IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY personID
HAVING cnt = 2
```

Comment: @Mahmoud Gamal: In mysql you can

Comment: @a1ex07, Didn't know that. This is not possible in SQL SERVER. Thanks

Comment: @dems: not necessary since you're not selecting a field OTHER than the one being aggregated, but normally... yes, group by would be required.

Comment: @MarcB - Really?  As far as I understood MySQL: Not having any field specified in the `GROUP BY` will always return just the one row. The selection of `personID` is allowed; it still just returns one value (non-deterministically chosen) but it doesn't change the level of grouping from `all` to `BY personID`. *[As a side effect, the `COUNT(personID)` will also be applied across all rows `WHERE sportID IN (1,2)`. This may mean that `HAVING cnt = 2` may never be satisfied as the result may always be much greater than 2.]*

Comment: AH yeah... right. monday mornings... remind me to not get up until around 5pm.