# How can I save PHP arrays to a MySQL database so that I can search through the arrays on the database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, relational-division

I'm trying to build a searchable database of the languages spoken by my users.

For example I might have

```
$john = array("english", "french", "spanish");
$jack = array("french", "spanish");
$jill = array("english", "spanish");
```

And I want to save them to a MySQL database so that I can later run something along the lines of (pseudo code)

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE spoken_languages = "french" and "spanish"
```

I know if I had `speaks_english`, `speaks_french`, and `speaks_spanish` columns then I could search for

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE speaks_french = "true" and speaks_spanish = "true"
```

But the scalability of adding a new column every time I encounter a new language is not very good. I've considered a table such as

```
john | english
john | french
john | spanish
jack | french
jack | spanish
jill | english
jill | spanish
```

Because at least then to get back languages spoken by a user I could just run

```
SELECT * FROM spoken_languages WHERE user = "jack"
```

But in order to search this for people that speak both french and spanish I would need to query for all of the users that speak french, all of the users that speak spanish and then calculate the intersections. That seems horribly inefficient.

So I ask you, how can I save this array of spoken languages so that I can search the database later without destroying the server?

Comment: your suggested table layout is the recommended one. you could tweak it to use user_id and language_id to make it smaller

Comment: A user table, a language table and a user / language table walk into a bar.... and a many to many relationship ensues.

Comment: Use the structure you considered, databases are good at doing the intersection thing as long as you know enough SQL

Comment: @RiggsFolly can you provide me with a sample? I'm not that great at SQL

Comment: Read up on many-to-many relationships. You'll end up with a `users` table, `languages` table, and a `users_languages` relationship table.

Comment: Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461194/filter-using-a-many-to-many-table-mysql

Comment: my demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23824f/1

Comment: @NickChapman There's no "search" done, you are assuming an implementation. The DBMS finds the rows that match the criteria you give, that's its business.

Comment: @JayBlanchard No, no, wait-- A user, a language and a DBMS walk into a bar... ...blah blah blah blah... ...and the bartender says, "...from DIFFERENT FIELDS but the SAME TABLE would GET INTO A ROW!"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the right solution in your question, with the `person_language` table that looks like this

```
john | english
john | french
jack | spanish
```

You can query it like so.

```
SELECT person
  FROM person_language
 WHERE language IN ( 'english', 'spanish')
 GROUP BY person
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Put an index on `(language, person)` and this will scale up fine.

If you want everybody who speaks Spanish and at least one other language you can do this.

```
 SELECT a.person
   FROM person_language AS a
   JOIN ( SELECT person
            FROM person_language
           GROUP BY person
          HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
        ) AS b ON a.person = b.person
  WHERE a.language = 'spanish'
```

This uses a JOIN directive to take the intersection of the people who speak spanish with the people who speak two or more languages.

Comment: Unrelated question, but would there be any significant performance differences if this query was written with the WHERE clause as `WHERE language = 'english' || language = 'spanish'`?

Comment: would not return the results required that way

Comment: @echochamber I believe that's the way MySQL runs the query. Either way, use explain on both queries to see any differences.

Comment: ...and I'm most likely wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782915/mysql-or-vs-in-performance

Answer (score 3):

You can do this query in an efficient way with a *self-join*:

```
SELECT * FROM users u1
JOIN users u2 USING (user)
WHERE (u1.lang, u2.lang) = ('french', 'spanish')
```

See examples of *relational division* solutions in my presentation, [SQL Query Patterns, Optimized](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-query-patterns-optimized).

If you have the right indexes, my tests show this self-join solution is about 20 times faster than the GROUP BY solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the three table setup like so

```sql
CREATE TABLE languages
(
  `id` int not null auto_increment primary key, 
  `language` varchar(32) unique
);
CREATE TABLE users
(
  `id` int not null auto_increment primary key,
  `name` varchar(32)
);
CREATE TABLE user_language
(
  `user_id` int, 
  `language_id` int,
  primary key (user_id, language_id)
);
```

IMHO if you're not having millions of users and all possible languages and looking for flexibility  and not fighting for miliseconds, especially if you check for more than 2 languages at a time, you can achieve it by using `MAX()` or `SUM()` aggregates in `HAVING` clause.

Here some sample queries for you:

```sql
-- Speaks both French AND Spanish
SELECT u.name
  FROM user_language ul JOIN languages l
    ON ul.language_id = l.id JOIN users u
    ON ul.user_id = u.id
 GROUP BY u.id
HAVING MAX(l.language = 'french') = 1
   AND MAX(l.language = 'spanish') = 1;
```

Output:

```
| NAME |
|------|
| John |
| Jack |
```

```sql
-- Speaks both French OR Spanish
SELECT u.name
  FROM user_language ul JOIN languages l
    ON ul.language_id = l.id JOIN users u
    ON ul.user_id = u.id
 GROUP BY u.id
HAVING MAX(l.language = 'french') +
       MAX(l.language = 'spanish') > 0;
```

Output:

```
| NAME |
|------|
| John |
| Jack |
| Jill |
```

```sql
-- Speaks any language French OR Spanish BUT NOT English
SELECT u.name
  FROM user_language ul JOIN languages l
    ON ul.language_id = l.id JOIN users u
    ON ul.user_id = u.id
 GROUP BY u.id
HAVING MAX(l.language = 'french') +
       MAX(l.language = 'spanish') > 0
   AND MAX(l.language = 'english') = 0;
```

Output:

```
| NAME |
|------|
| Jack |
```

```sql
-- Speaks any language but English
SELECT u.name
  FROM user_language ul JOIN languages l
    ON ul.language_id = l.id JOIN users u
    ON ul.user_id = u.id
 GROUP BY u.id
HAVING MAX(l.language = 'english') = 0;
```

Output:

```
| NAME |
|------|
| Jack |
```

```sql
-- What languages does Jack speak
SELECT l.language
  FROM user_language ul JOIN languages l
    ON ul.language_id = l.id JOIN users u
    ON ul.user_id = u.id
 WHERE u.name = 'Jack';
```

Output:

```
| LANGUAGE |
|----------|
|   french |
|  spanish |
```

```sql
-- How many languages do users speak
SELECT u.name, COUNT(*) no_of_languages
  FROM users u LEFT JOIN user_language ul
    ON u.id = ul.user_id
 GROUP BY u.id;
```

Output:

```
| NAME | NO_OF_LANGUAGES |
|------|-----------------|
| John |               3 |
| Jack |               2 |
| Jill |               2 |
```

```sql
-- How many users do speak a particular language
SELECT l.language, COUNT(*) no_of_users
  FROM languages l LEFT JOIN user_language ul
    ON l.id = ul.language_id
 GROUP BY l.id;
```

Output:

```
| LANGUAGE | NO_OF_USERS |
|----------|-------------|
|  english |           2 |
|   french |           2 |
|  spanish |           3 |
```

---

**Now** in a **real application** you most likely won't be using language or user names but rather deal with ids that are coming from your UI (drop down boxes or whatever). Therefore you'll be able to eliminate one join from the equation and your query would look rather like this

```sql
-- Speaks both French AND Spanish with Ids
SELECT u.name
  FROM user_language ul JOIN users u
    ON ul.user_id = u.id
 GROUP BY u.id
HAVING MAX(ul.language_id = 2) = 1
   AND MAX(ul.language_id = 3) = 1;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a3f7/5)** demo